# will cellmeasurer work for divs rendererd by dangerouslySetInnerHtml

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I am trying to create a prototype of List with dynamic row heights. I am trying to use CellMeasurer for the measuring the rowHeights. I am getting the html of list items from the server. It is somewhat related to an item in the facebook news feed. I need to dynamically determine the height of the following element which I have placed in the rowRenderer mentioned below.

```
   <div  style={style} key={key}>
   <div className={key}   style={style}  key={key}  >
   <div  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html2jsx }}></div>
   </div>
```

The entire component has been copied below:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { List } from 'react-virtualized';
    import './FeedListView.css'
    import link from 'react';
    import { CellMeasurer, CellMeasurerCache, Grid } from 'react-virtualized';
    // List data as an array of strings
    class FeedListViewDynamicHeight extends Component {
    
    
      render() {
        const cache = new CellMeasurerCache({
          defaultWidth: 825,
           minWidth: 825,
           fixedHeight: true
        });
    
    
        function rowRenderer ({
          key,         // Unique key within array of rows
          index,       // Index of row within collection
          parent,   // This row is visible within the List (eg it is not an overscanned row)
          style        // Style object to be applied to row (to position it)
        }) {
          return (
    
                <CellMeasurer
                  cache={cache}
                  columnIndex={0}
                  key={key}
                  rowIndex={index}
                  parent={parent}
                  style={style}
                  >
    
    
             <div  style={style} key={key}>
             <div className={key}   style={style}  key={key}  >
             <div  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html2jsx }}></div>
              </div>
                   
                  </div>
    
    
    
    
       </CellMeasurer>
     );
    
        }
        return (
    
          <div>
    
          <List
          width={825}
          height={200}
          rowCount={1}
          rowHeight={cache.rowHeight}
          rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
          />
          </div>
    
    
        );
      }
    }
```

1.Is it possible for cellRenderer to calculate height for rows set through dangerouslySetInnerHtml? DangerouslySetInnerHtml can include images/text links of varying heights.

2.If I do give a static row height I see a lot of empty space where the row sizes are actually smaller than rowHeight specified. How to avoid such cases?

Update:

I changed the static html code to a component and then tried cell measurer. The height is being taken as the default height of 30px for the first 75 components and CellMeasurer only seems to work when the height parameter is crossed. Attaching the screen shot and code

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  import { List } from 'react-virtualized';
  import Post from './Post'

  import link from 'react';
  import styles from './main-header.css'
  import { CellMeasurer, CellMeasurerCache, Grid } from 'react-virtualized';



  import ReactHtmlParser, { processNodes, convertNodeToElement, htmlparser2 } from 'react-html-parser';
  // List data as an array of strings
  class FeedListViewDynamicHeight extends Component {

    _cache = new CellMeasurerCache({
      fixedWidth: true,
      });

    _rowRenderer = ({ index, isScrolling, key, parent, style }) => {



       var post={
         groupName:"Product Management- Discussions",
         postImageUrl:"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0__DD-Wo-4z4cB8Q7d6jip7IyZB4eBiF_dFaPx7wanMDdqX6Ab5juODD0WydT",
         name:"Karan Thakral",
         role:"Worked at Cisco Systems",
         lastupdated:"2 mins ago",
         text:"Slack introduces shared channels to facilitate inter company chat, interesting developmenb Slack introduces shared channels to facilitate inter company chat, interesting developmen Slack introduces shared channels to facilitate inter company chat, interesting developmen Slack introduces shared channels to facilitate inter company chat, interesting developmen Slack introduces shared channels to facilitate inter company chat, interesting development",
         like:"0",
         comment:"1",
         share:"2"
         }

         let content;
          content=  <Post post={post}/>


      return (
        <CellMeasurer
          cache={this._cache}
          columnIndex={0}
          key={key}
          parent={parent}
          rowIndex={index}

        >

          // 'style' attribute required to position cell (within parent List)
          <div key={key} className={key} style={style}>
            {content}
          </div>
        

        </CellMeasurer>
      );
    };
    render() {







      return (

        <div>

        <List
        width={825}
        height={2000}
        rowCount={100000}
        rowHeight={this._cache.rowHeight}
        rowRenderer={this._rowRenderer}
      />
        </div>


      );
    }
  }

  export default FeedListViewDynamicHeight;
```

Attaching the screenshot below
[image]

In the picture you can see the height changes from 30px to 481px from the 76th to the 77div? Unable to understand this problem

Comment: How to resize rows dynamically when the dimension of list elements are not known?

Answer (score 2):

> 1.Is it possible for cellRenderer to calculate height for rows set through dangerouslySetInnerHtml? DangerouslySetInnerHtml can include images/text links of varying heights.

Sure, but you'll need to let `CellMeasurer` know to actually measure the cell once async content (like images) have finished loading. The [`CellMeasurer` docs](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/CellMeasurer.md#using-cellmeasurer-with-images) show an example of this with a normal React render method:

```
function rowRenderer ({ index, isScrolling, key, parent, style }) {
  const source // This comes from your list data

  return (
    <CellMeasurer
      cache={cache}
      columnIndex={0}
      key={key}
      parent={parent}
      rowIndex={index}
    >
      {({ measure }) => (
        // 'style' attribute required to position cell (within parent List)
        <div style={style}>
          <img
            onLoad={measure}
            src={source}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </CellMeasurer>
  );
}
```

You would need to adapt the example to handle the fact that you're setting HTML directly.

> 2.If I do give a static row height I see a lot of empty space where the row sizes are actually smaller than rowHeight specified. How to avoid such cases?

Not to sound sassy but...don't do this? If you're giving a static height and rows are shorter, then of course you'll see empty space. You need to give an accurate height. This is why `CellMeasurer` exists. :)

This is a great reference component: https://github.com/bvaughn/tweets/blob/master/src/components/TweetList.js

It powers the demo fake-Twitter-app I created: https://tweets.now.sh/

I suggest checking out the source code for examples of similar newsfeed-like lists.

Comment: Hi Brian thanks for your response.For the moment i changed html to a proper react component and i tried running with the CellMeasurer again. Seeing a peculiar behaviour. The height for the rowHeight is being taken as 30px which as per the code is the defaultRowHeight and i am seeing this height for all the components which are within the limit of the "height" parameter. When the rowCount*rowHeight  crosses the height parameter the height of the component is being correctly calculated. I updated the question with the code and screenshots

Comment: Link me to a repro (CodeSandbox, Plnkr, something).

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for the response. Please find the CodeSandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/r1w5110p34

Comment: On potential problem is that you seem to be passing `measure` to the `Post` component via an `onLoad` prop that isn't actually used anywhere. And even if it were used, the image URLs in your `post` objects aren't valid so the `<img onLoad={...}>` would not get called anyway. Here's a forked version that uses the `measure` callback and sets valid image URLs so it's triggered: https://codesandbox.io/s/92xvk9r6xo

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for the response. My bad I was using a wrong variable name for imageUrl. Can more examples with async data be included in the documentation on the usage of measure it will be really helpful. Thanks for writing a wonderful library.

Comment: You're welcome!

Docs are kind of hard to create and maintain. :) That's why I also create some sample projects like tweets.now.sh. But yeah, more CellMeasurer docs and examples could be useful... I agree.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when I rendered a different kind of list on another page.
I released that `cache` was initialized outside of the component. After move cache into the component, the issue is resolved.

```
const DemoList = () => {
  const cache = new CellMeasurerCache({
    defaultHeight: 50,
    fixedWidth: true,
  });


  const rowRenderer = ({ index, key, parent, style }) => {
      const line = logs[index];
      const __html = convert.toHtml(line.message);
      const content = <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: convert.toHtml(line.message)}} />
  }

    return (
      <CellMeasurer
        key={key}
        cache={cache}
        columnIndex={0}
        parent={parent}
        rowIndex={index}
      >
        {({ measure, registerChild }) => (
          <div ref={registerChild} style={style}>
            {content}
          </div>
        )}
      </CellMeasurer>
    );
  };


  return (
    <div style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <AutoSizer>
        {({ height, width }) => (
          <List
            height={height}
            width={width}
            rowCount={logs.length}
            deferredMeasurementCache={cache}
            rowHeight={cache.rowHeight}
            rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
          />
        )}
      </AutoSizer>
    </div>
  );
}
```